Pwa building using bubblewrap is getting error
I have given bubblewrap build command after generating android project (APP FROM PWA) from an existing keystore. But it throws error. I am not able to create new keystore. May be because my app is already there in the play store. So I am trying to make it from existing keystore file.
Once I give bubblewrap build and give the passwords it throws a error message spawn EINVAL. WHY?
I have given bubblewrap build command after generating android project (APP FROM PWA) from an existing keystore. But it throws error. I am not able to create new keystore. May be because my app is already there in the play store. So I am trying to make it from existing keystore file.
Once I give bubblewrap build and give the passwords it throws a error message spawn EINVAL. WHY?
